# What's the pitch accent of すなわち?

Tags: phonology, pitch-accent

As in title, what's the pattern of the pitch accent in the word すなわち, in the Tokyo (standard) pronunciation?

Comment: FWIW, the Daijirin dictionary often provides pitch accent patterns.  The Weblio resource aggregator website includes Daijirin in its JA-JA dictionaries.  [Click here for the すなわち entry](http://www.weblio.jp/content/%E3%81%99%E3%81%AA%E3%82%8F%E3%81%A1).

Comment: UPDATE: Due to an apparent change in licensing terms, Daijirin has vanished from all online sources that I know of, as of some time in mid-to-late 2020.

Answer (score 4):

It is 「[すなわち]{LHLL}」.

Same as 「[スタイル]{LHLL}」